# mysql setting up encryption (ssl) without client certificats

Tags: mysql, ssl, certificate

I would like to setup SSL encryption for my MySQL servers to let users encrypt their connections without being themselves fully authenticated (like an anonymous access, but still encrypted). I would like to add more security by this way for clients requesting directly my servers.

I have succeeded into encrypting the connection, but I have no idea whether this is possible without client certificates, and neither google or mysql doc are of much help. I just would like to know if this is even possible; (and if so, some advices on how to do it would be highly appreciated);

I am working on debian systems (Wheezy, MySQL version:5.5.29).

Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Client certificates are not required unless you set the [`REQUIRE X509`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/grant.html#grant-other-characteristics) option for the account.